# Displaying a chart/graph from Python script in Android Studio

Tags: android, python, matplotlib

I have a Python sentiment analysis function that outputs a chart or graph using the [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) library. It can also return json if needed.

I'm using Flask as the API. The next job is to try and get this graph to display in Android Studio.

I have looked and cant seem to find a way to get the graph returned from the function to display on Android studio. What is the best way to render graphs in Android? Would it be to get the function to return Json and plot the graph based on these values?

--Edit. Since initial post. Somebody has pointed me towards [HelloCharts](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android) for Android, and getting the function to return Json values for HelloCharts to render.

Comment: It isn't clear to me, are you using Python in your Android app?

Comment: No, sorry i'll clarify. Im going to be using calls from my Android front end to call, through the API, the function which then returns the needed values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using [this library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for displaying charts on Android. You can look through tutorial there to figure out how to pass your data to assign values to build a chart

Comment: Thank you. Looks just like what I need. Will try and implement it now